# How to archive mail when use gmail api send message with threadid？

Tags: gmail-api

we send alarm mail to our alarm mail group,a python script use gmailapi read the alarm mail,I need send a reminder email  to  everyone in the alarm mail group when script read  alarm mail , this is my functon

```
def send_message_with_thread(to, subject, thread_id, message_text, service):
    if type(message_text) != str:
        message_text = str(message_text)

    message = MIMEText(message_text, 'html')
    message['to'] = to+
    message['from'] = settings.READ_MAIL
    message['subject'] = subject
    raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
    raw = raw.decode()
    body = {'raw': raw, 'threadId': thread_id}
    messages = service.users().messages()
    send = messages.send(userId='me', body=body).execute()
```

Now,I hope the reminder email archive with alarm mail,but I find everyone's mail thread id is different ,Although this email was sent to the alarm mail group and everyone in the alarm mail group .

Answer (score 0):

### To archive a mail, you need to remove the label `INBOX` from it

- This can be done with [users.messages.modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/modify) providing the request body

```
{
  "removeLabelIds": [
    "INBOX"
  ]
}
```

- It is not possible to archive emails in the `Sent` folder
- As for the email in the receivers `Inbox`, you are correct:
  the `message id` will be different for every user event if the email was sent to a Google group.
- So you would need to find for each user the `message id` e.g. by using the query parameter `q` with the method  [messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list)
- Example query:
  `to:NAME_OF_GOOGLEGROUP AND from:XXX AND subject:XXX"`